# Recording and Checking the disk read write speed of a python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pci-e

I have created a simple python program using the pypcie package on Linux(Ubuntu) so that I can access a 1GB DDR3 memory on an fpga board through pcie. I want to test the throughput of my program  when writing 1GB to the DDR3 module and reading 1GB from the DDR3 module separately. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which part of measuring the speed is problematic? I'd say all you need to do to measure the speed of anything is: 1 look at the clock, 2 do something, 3 look at the clock again, 4 calculate the time difference.

Comment: Since I know the size of the data I want to write that is possible, but I would then want to know, is there a way that python can keep track of the time for each operation since looking at the clock manually is kind of unpractical

Comment: Of course, "looking at the clock" is something you can do in the code. You can use `time.monotoinc()`or `time.perf_counter()`, depending on the expected duration, or wanted precision.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the use cases of these function a read.